# List directories in localhost using lftp cmd

Tags: bash, local, lftp

I'm trying to copy a file to a folder in localhost using lftp command but I'm having troubles executing commands.
When I try to list folders in a directory using : `!dir`;

I get the following error : `stderr: 1. bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create! 2. sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token ;;' 3. sh: -c: line 0: dir;;`

Comment: !dir is an FTP command, dont think it works with lftp. use "local ls" instead

Comment: I tried 'ls' still the same error

Comment: Post your script / all commands please.